# How can I calculate percentages of a list of numbers?

Tags: math, percentage

Here is an example of what I'm trying to calculate.

I have 4 different items in a list and how many of each.  Ex:

```
Box1 contains 3.2 items
Box2 contains 6.1 items
Box3 contains 4.0 items
Box4 contains 1.8 items
```

What I would like to calculate is the percentage of each Box.  The result would look something like:

```
Box1 contains 3.2 items = 17%
Box2 contains 6.1 items = 51%
Box3 contains 4.0 items = 24%
Box4 contains 1.8 items = 8%

Total = 100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that this question is presented without a language tag, I've drafted a solution in Java.

Calculate the total items:

```
double total= 0;
for(int i = 0; i < boxList.size(); i++)
{
  total += boxList[i].getItems();
}
```

Calculate the percentage of items held by each box:

```
for(int i = 0; i < boxList.size(); i++)
{
  double ithPercentage = (boxList[i].getItems()/total) * 100.0d;
  //output the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `C#` use LINQ

```
var sum = list.Sum(item=>item.Quantity);
var pctList = list.Select(item=>item.Quantity/sum);
```